# How do I use a function I created on values within a dataframe and replace the values with outcome of the function?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I created a function called `getExpressionLevel` and the question asks me to use this function to replace the numbers with the statements below. So what do I need to use to achieve this?

Function for getExpressionLevel;

```
function(a)    {
  if    (a<5)    {
  cat    ("none")
  }

 if    (a>=5&a<20)    {
  cat    ("low")
 }

 if    (a>=20&a<60)    {
  cat    ("medium")
 }

  if    (a>=60)    {
  cat    ("high")
  }
}
```

- "none" for expression levels below 5
- "low" for expression levels higher or equal to 5 and lower than 20
- "medium" for expression levels higher or equal to 20 and lower than 60
- "high" for expression levels higher or equal to 60

And the question is;

Create a `data.frame` called `expression_levels`, which has 10 row (one for each gene) and 3 columns
(one for each cell line). Then compute average expression for each each gene in each cell line and using
`getExpressionLevel` function label the expression accordingly.

This is my current data.frame. The data within it needs to replaced with the outcomes of the getExpressionfunction.

```
  genename       Kc167         BG3         S2

1   Clic        7.333333      48.33333      75.00000

2   Treh        24.666667     12.66667      52.33333

3   bib         31.333333      79.33333     82.00000

4   CalpC       65.000000     69.33333      63.66667

5   tud         59.666667     81.66667      16.33333

6   cort        74.333333     50.66667      28.66667

7   S2P         72.000000     39.66667      50.66667

8   Mitofilin   38.333333     29.00000      54.66667

9   Oxp         73.666667     49.33333      42.66667

10  Ada1-2      87.333333     42.00000      28.00000
```

This is the expected data.frame:

```
          Kc167      BG3        S2

 Clic       low      medium     high

 Treh      medium     low      medium

 bib       medium     high      high

 CalpC      high      high      high

 tud       medium     high      low

 cort       high     medium    medium

 S2P        high      medium   medium

 MitofiliN medium    medium    medium

 Oxp        high      medium   medium

 Ada1-2     high      medium   medium
```

Comment: This is a very nice question, but please note there are some formatting possibilities you could use to make it even clearer. In particular, the code needs to be indented by 4 spaces, and the bullet points are best marked with ordinary `*` or `-` characters.

Comment: Hello, I tried to edit my question but could not work out to re-create the data.frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional way. It's always helpful to know how to play with functions.

```
## sample data
df <- data.table(genename = c('Clic','Treh','bib','CalpC'),
                 Kc167 = c(7.333,24.666,31.3333,65),
                 BG3 = c(48.33,12.66,79.33,69.33),
                 S2 = c(75.00,52.33,82.00,63.66))

## this function updates values based on following criterias
get_values <- function(x)
{
    if(x < 5) return ('None')
    else if ((x >= 5) && (x < 20)) return ('low')
    else if ((x >= 20) && (x < 60)) return ('medium')
    else if (x >= 60) return ('high')
}

## creating a new data frame with answers
df2 <- df$genename
df2$Kc167 <- sapply(df$Kc167, get_values)
df2$BG3 <- sapply(df$BG3, get_values)
df2$S2 <- sapply(df$S2, get_values)

  genename  Kc167    BG3     S2
1:     Clic    low medium   high
2:     Treh medium    low medium
3:      bib medium   high   high
4:    CalpC   high   high   high
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
bin_breaks <- c(-Inf, 5, 20, 60, Inf)
bin_labels <- c("none", "low", "medium", "high")
df[,-1] <- sapply(df[,-1], function(x) cut(x, 
                                           breaks = bin_breaks, 
                                           labels = bin_labels, 
                                           right = F))
df
```

Output is:

```
    genename  Kc167    BG3     S2
1       Clic    low medium   high
2       Treh medium    low medium
3        bib medium   high   high
4      CalpC   high   high   high
5        tud medium   high    low
6       cort   high medium medium
7        S2P   high medium medium
8  Mitofilin medium medium medium
9        Oxp   high medium medium
10    Ada1-2   high medium medium
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(genename = c("Clic", "Treh", "bib", "CalpC", "tud", 
"cort", "S2P", "Mitofilin", "Oxp", "Ada1-2"), Kc167 = c(7.333333, 
24.666667, 31.333333, 65, 59.666667, 74.333333, 72, 38.333333, 
73.666667, 87.333333), BG3 = c(48.33333, 12.66667, 79.33333, 
69.33333, 81.66667, 50.66667, 39.66667, 29, 49.33333, 42), S2 = c(75, 
52.33333, 82, 63.66667, 16.33333, 28.66667, 50.66667, 54.66667, 
42.66667, 28)), .Names = c("genename", "Kc167", "BG3", "S2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

**Edit:** Appropriate `right` parameter is added in the code to satisfy boundary condition & OP's requirement (courtesy @drf).

Comment: One small suggestion -- you may want to add the `ordered_result=TRUE` and `right=TRUE` parameters to the `cut` call to handle the boundary conditions and produce an ordered factor.

Comment: Thnx @drf! Here to satisfy OP's requirement I think it would be `right=F` since the break is like `[b1, b2)` i.e. closed on left.